# Unintended merges on bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

Why these merge saying develop to develop appears in Bitbucket when I haven't done any merging? what these mean? Am I doing something wrong?

I use `git push origin develop` to push my changes to remote

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably been using `git pull` to pull upstream changes into your local repository. Hence the message:

> Merge branch 'develop' of https://bitbucket.org/org/repo *(the remote
>   repository hosted at Bitbucket)* into develop *(your local copy of the
>   'develop' branch)*

Remember that `git pull` is essentially a `git fetch` + `git merge`. So it will do a fast-forward merge when possible, but if your local repository and the remote repository have diverged, Git will perform a three-way merge instead (which creates a new commit, as in your screenshot).

Git should then ask you to enter a commit message:

> ```
> Merge branch 'develop' of https://bitbucket.org/org/repo into develop
>
> # Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
> # especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
> #
> # Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
> # the commit.
> ```

I wouldn't worry too much about the merges. However, I personally prefer a different workflow, using forks and branching:

- Fork the repository to your personal account
- Create a new branch for every feature, bugfix, etc. you work on (I don't use a 'develop' branch, so I just branch off the master branch)
- Make some commits
- Push the commits to a new branch on your personal fork
- When the feature/bugfix/etc. is complete, create a pull request that merges your branch into the shared repository's master branch.

This will limit the amount of three-way merges because you are the only one that's working on your fork of the repository. And by rebasing from time to time you can stay up-to-date with recent changes to the main repository without having to merge constantly.

However, every time a pull request is merged there **will** be a merge commit. But, as I said, I wouldn't worry about that.

(I'm not telling you you should use this workflow, but this is just my personal preference and how we do it at my company.)

Comment: Thanks for the information. You are right we usually do git pull. But if there are any merges required then shouldn't I get these messages or this all happen behind the scene?

Comment: I don't know if you are the one who made the merge commits, but you should probably get a screen to specify the commit message. See my updated answer.